# jQuery spectrum color picker

Tags: jquery, picker, spectrum

I am using jquery spectrum color picker. Is there a way to get spectrum selector within the change event?

If I apply spectrum to multiple elements by class (hap-ch), can I get active selector instance?

```
<input id="playerBgColor" class="hap-ch">
<input id="playerBgColor2" class="hap-ch">
<input id="playerBgColor3" class="hap-ch">

$(".hap-ch").spectrum({
    change: function(color) {
        //how to get playerBgColor id here?
    },
});
```

I know I can apply spectrum individually like this:

```
 $("#playerBgColor ").spectrum({
    change: function(color) {

    },
});
```

But I wanted to know if I can reuse this code for multiple spectrums like in first example.

Comment: Could you add a `demo fiddle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I just played around and yea, you can make use of `$(this)` within `change`, which will refer to current `input element`.

```
$(".hap-ch").spectrum({
    change: function(color) {
            alert($(this).attr('id')); //there you get the id
    },
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ctkY3/5115/)**